What is the colon doing in this example, and how is it doing it?
I found the following code snippet in a utils.d.ts file in the @xyflow module, and can not understand how, what or why it does, what it does.
I'm mostly confused by the colon after "oppositePosition", as I thought in this context it should be followed by a "type" in form of a string, but it's followed instead by an Object, which contains the directions, with what I assume to be a "type" again, but also no actual assigned values.
utils.d.ts
export declare enum Position {
    Left = "left",
    Top = "top",
    Right = "right",
    Bottom = "bottom"
}
export declare const oppositePosition: {
    left: Position;
    right: Position;
    top: Position;
    bottom: Position;
};

But when imported the const oppositePosition can actually be used to quickly gain the opposite of the 4 directions like oppositePosition["right"]; //returns "left", as when compiled with rollup it somehow generates the following code:
bundle.js
var Position;
(function (Position) {
  Position["Left"] = "left";
  Position["Top"] = "top";
  Position["Right"] = "right";
  Position["Bottom"] = "bottom";
})(Position || (Position = {}));
const oppositePosition = {
  [Position.Left]: Position.Right,
  [Position.Right]: Position.Left,
  [Position.Top]: Position.Bottom,
  [Position.Bottom]: Position.Top
};

What kind of constructor magic is this?

The "object" is the interface. It's called object type I see the term "constructor" in the question and in the tags, but I don't see any constructor in the code.

Is your question about a colon or about how TS builds work? If colon: utils.d.ts is a TypeScript declaration file. All it does it say what types things will be, so importers of the module can get type hints. That colon is a type annotation. export declare const oppositePosition: {⋯} is just saying that the module exports a constant named oppositePosition which has the type {⋯}.

(see prev comment). Or if how builds work: presumably both utils.d.ts and bundle.js are compiled from the TS code. They are not directly related to each other (i.e., utils.d.ts does not get compiled into bundle.js). You're not showing us the source code, so it's hard to say exactly.  Please [edit] your question to clearly ask a single primary question and then let me know if you'd like to see one of these fleshed out into an answer post.

It's nothing too fancy. export declare const oppositePosition: {...} defines a variable with the type specified as {...}.
Another way you can write it is this:
interface OppositeMap {
    left: Position;
    right: Position;
    top: Position;
    bottom: Position;
};

export declare const oppositePosition: OppositeMap;

As for the generated code, JS doesn't have enums, so the way typescript converts the enums to JS equivalent is to generate an IIFE which creates the enum as an object, and then creates the oppositionPosition object from that.
However, as I've been reminded of in the comments, since this is a declaration file and oppositePosition has been declared, typescript will not generate any new code. Remove all uses of declare in the file, to see what typescript generates. You will also need to add a definition for oppositePosition.
Playground Link

Right now I'm guessing this question is an XY problem. They are confused about how utils.d.ts gets compiled into bundler.js, and think the answer has something to do with the colon in the declaration file, but that's not what's happening. What's presumably actually happening is there's some TS source code which is used to generate both utils.d.ts and bundler.js. But if we focus on "what is going on with that colon" then we're looking at the wrong thing X when the actual issue is Y.

"then creates the oppositionPosition object from that." it doesn't. Nothing in this code creates or assigns oppositePosition. The keyword define only lets TS know that it is defined elsewhere and not to consider it undeclared. It does not do anything else with the emitted code. Ergo, oppositePosition is created in some different place.  .d.ts files in general are ambient-only and do not any runtime artefacts.

"Remove all uses of declare in the file, to see what typescript generates." It will generate an error on oppositePosition since it's not initialized. See my first comment.

Or, as I said in my first comment, the actual source code is located elsewhere and they should look at that instead of the .d.ts file in the first place
